# Interpretation of blocks in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In the node REPL, if we enter {1}, the REPL prints 1, as though the value of the block statement is 1. In a script, the same {1} executes without any complaint. But one cannot assign the block {1} to a variable, since {1} is not an expression.

So, what is the validity of a loose block such as { 1 } ? How is it interpreted ?

Comment: Notionally, the value of a block is the value associated with the last statement in it, but that behavior is not available in the language directly. It's odd but that's how it works.

Comment: @Pointy Isn't it in the language? I read [14.2.2 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation, step 7. Return ? `blockValue`.](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation) as returning the value of the execution of the statements with in the block.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes it is in the language *spec*, but in practical terms there's no syntax for assigning the "result" of a block as part of an expression. At least, there's no way I can think of.